# Instantiate persistent app state with AsyncStorage

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

I'm trying to create an object that will serve as my app's persistent state. That means the first time state is referenced after the app starts  up, it needs to load the state object from AsyncStorage. Here's what I've got so far:

```
var instance = null;

var State = {
  user: "bob",

  update(newState) {
    Object.assign(instance, newState);
    AsyncStorage.setItem('appState', JSON.stringify(instance)).then(() => {
      AsyncStorage.getItem('appState', (err, result) => {
        console.log(result)
      })
    })
  }
}

module.exports = (() => {
  if (!instance) {
    return AsyncStorage.getItem('appState').then((value) => {
      if (value) {
        instance = value
        console.log("assigning saved state")
      } else {
        instance = State
        console.log("assigning fresh state")
        AsyncStorage.setItem('appState', JSON.stringify(instance))
      }
        return instance
    })
  } else {
    console.log("using existing state")
    return instance
  }
})();
```

Right now, this returns the promise when I try and use it. Is there any way to extract my object value from the promise, or a better pattern to accomplish what I'm trying to do? Perhaps I'll have to just initialize State on startup.

Comment: i would actually move the startup to a callback/promise on the storage that fires once the store is initialized. that way, you don't have to split hairs in the app logic. that may involve splitting the startup code into two parts: without state and with state...

Comment: Where exactly you want to extract the object from the promise? You are already returning 'instance'. So if you follow with then() you will get the instance value. A problem I see is that if instance is already set you are returning it directly. You should always return a promise so the function is consistent.

Comment: @dandavis: I'm not sure what you mean, could you provide an example?

Comment: you said you reference the state after startup, but i'm saying don't startup until the state is loaded from the store. that way, you can have sync access to the state and not mess with promises everytime you need a stored value.

Comment: @carlosdubusm The goal is to be able to access the state by saying 'State.user' in the app.

Comment: @dandavis so you mean I should initialize my state as the app boots? Is there a designated place I should put that?

Comment: i don't know how you're structuring your app, so i can't really help there. just the other day i implemented a storage that needs a password, so it's very async and the whole app really needs the stored values. i moved most of the app startup routine to a new function that is called once the password is entered and the store unlocked. i got a cold startup and a warm startup instead of just a startup, if that helps explain what i mean...

Comment: @dandavis Yes I see what you mean, I just need to figure out where I should be putting initialization code like this in a react native app. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I have a workable solution. Essentially, I delayed the initialization of the app until the state was loaded via AsyncStorage. This is necessary, since it's the state that tells the app whether to start at the login screen or not. In my root file:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      stateLoaded: false
    }
    State.initialize().then(() => {
      this.setState({stateLoaded: true})
    })
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.stateLoaded) {
      return (
          // Your startup code
      );
    } else {
      return (
        // Your loading screen code
    }
  }
}
```

And in my State class:

```
initialize() {
    if (!this.initialized) {
      return AsyncStorage.getItem('appState').then(value=>JSON.parse(value))
      .then((value) => {
        if (value) {
          Object.assign(this, value)
          console.log("assigning saved state")
        } else {
          console.log("assigning fresh state")
          AsyncStorage.setItem('appState', JSON.stringify(this))
        }
        this.intialized = true
        return this
      })
    } else {
      return promise.resolve(this)
    }
  }
}
```

Now, I can safely reference variables from `State` throughout my app, since initialization happens before anything else. As far as I know, this is the best (only?) way to do this. If that's not the case let me know, because this is pretty ugly.

Comment: Looks good to me. Followed this approach and also worked out. Not the prettiest, but simple and efficient. In my case I used this to ensure I loaded the preferred language.